# How to change one part of file name in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I am fairly new to Bash and don't know how to do much. I have a series of folder and within those folders I have a few files, for example in the first folder I might have:

- file1_0.extension
- file1_1.extension
- file1_2.extension
- ...
- file1_9.extension
- file1_10.extension
- file1_11.extension
- ...

And so on. What I would like to do is write a Bash script that goes through all folders and change the first 10 filenames so that it instead looks like this:

- file1_00.extension
- file1_01.extension
- file1_02.extension
- ...
- file1_09.extension
- file1_10.extension
- file1_11.extension
- ...

Would anyone be able to explain how this can be done in Bash? I am fairly new to Bash scripting

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346917/rename-files-to-add-leading-zeros-to-numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can use "rename" command to do the trick.

First, using "rename -v" to see whether it's installed, if not, you can use this command for Ubuntu

```
sudo apt install rename
```

Or for SUSE

```
zypper install rename
```

Then simply use

```
rename -e 's/file1_([0-9]).extension/file1_0$1.extension/' -- *.extension
```

This can rename the files as you'd like to.